# Dependencies in profiles.clj aren't loaded in lein repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

.lein/profiles.clj has dependencies as,

```
{:user {}
     :repl {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                       [ring/ring "1.1.6"]]
        }}
```

in repl

```
(require 'ring.adapter.jetty)
```

throws,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate ring/adapter/jetty__init.class or ring/adapter/jetty.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

This means, `ring` dependency is not loaded in repl shell. Any mistakes?

Comment: That is an older version of both ring and Clojure. The current version of ring's dependency block is [ring "1.3.2"]. Could you try with  a more recent ring version and Clojure 1.6+ and include any errors reported by running "lein deps"

Comment: Library dependencies should almost certainly be in the project.clj file in this project rather than in you lein profile file. Could you include the project.clj file for this project.

Comment: there is no project. i am running it from bash shell... like nodejs repl, that can be ran from any directory...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend reading https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md as I'm not sure you are using profiles correctly. In particular, at the end it shows a way of debugging your profiles, which will show you what is going on.

Secondly, I'm not sure about "there is no project - I am running it from bash shell". If your loading jetty and using ring, you will also need code which sets handlers, routes and probably middleware. this means code files, which means a project tree. Create a basic project with lein new  and run from the root of that project.

However, if you really do need to do it as you say, I would suggest you just do

{:user {:dependencies [[....]]}} as your profiles.clj as I suspect that what is happening is that lein is not loading your :repl profile. You could also try running lein with the explicit profile i.e. lein with-profile +repl repl